# How to find out what system processes an executable/app uses OS X?

Tags: macos, networking, firewall, process

I'm trying to find a way to find out what other processes an executable uses so i can block/unblock the app and those processes on my firewall.

For example, Google Drive app uses Discoveryd to startup over the internet and without letting the discoveryd process & the app itself through the firewall Google Drive will not start.

The way i'm doing it now is to look at a network monitoring utility app (i.e Little Snitch, TcpBlock), close all other apps and run google drive on its own and the outgoing network traffic in the monitoring window is now the apps traffic only. It would be good to be able to do this without closing every other app.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This  isn't a failsafe way, but you can see process hierarchy in Activity Monitor. If a process launches a child process, going to View -> All Processes, Hierarchically in the menu bar will reveal them.

[image]